# How to reauthorise a Google account in Internet Accounts (after changing Google Account password) on Mac OS 10.11

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail, google

My Google Account is connected to Mac OS X using Internet Accounts. I changed the password of my Google Account (at google.com) and now the OS - and especially Mac Mail - can no longer access the account.

I believe that Mac OS X is using OAuth to authorise with Google, so is it possible to force the OS to reauthorise the connected account (without deleting and starting again)?

Mac OS Version: 10.11.3

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried opening System Preferences > Internet Accounts? Opening it will usually ask you to reauthorize when you've changed passwords. If not you can try checking and unchecking Notes.

Comment: Yes, and that hasn't worked, unfortunately.